# Junit: MethodNotFoundException with PowerMock

Tags: java, exception, junit, powermock, dbunit

While running DBUnit based junit test case, I get following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@2a5f1994 failed.
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:92)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No method found with name 'assertNoAnnotations' with parameter types: [ java.lang.reflect.Field, [Ljava.lang.Class; ] in class org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.throwExceptionIfMethodWasNotFound(WhiteboxImpl.java:1247)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findMethodOrThrowException(WhiteboxImpl.java:985)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:882)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:713)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.process(PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java:45)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.injectSpiesAndInjectToSetters(AnnotationEnabler.java:55)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:50)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90)
    ... 18 more
```

My class looks like:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SampleDbTest extends {

    /** service mock */
    @InjectMocks
    private TestService testService;

    /** entity manager. */
    EntityManager                    entityManager;

    /**
     * Sets the up.
     * 
     * @throws Exception the exception
     */
    @Before
    public final void setUp() throws Exception {
        // get entity manager
        injectField(testService, "entityManager", entityManager);
    }
    ....
    ....
```

Here TestService is stateless session bean interface. I am not able to find any explanation anywhere for this weird exception. Please let me know, if you have any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you use incompatible versions of PowerMock and Mockito.

If you look at your stacktrack, you will see, that exception is thrown by `PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine` and this class can't find `assertNoAnnotations` method.

Last version of Powermock is 1.5.6. So, look now at src of this class for an older version of PowerMock ([1.4.12](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.4.12/org/powermock/api/mockito/internal/configuration/PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java?av=f), as example) and you will see, that there is invoke of `assertNoAnnotations` method processed. Starting from [1.5](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.5/org/powermock/api/mockito/internal/configuration/PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java?av=f) version, this class don't use such invoke.

Last version of Mockito is 1.9.5. Now, if you look at src of the `InjectingAnnotationEngine` ( which is extended by `PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine` ) for [1.9.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.9.0/org/mockito/internal/configuration/InjectingAnnotationEngine.java?av=f) version of Mockito, you will see, that there is `assertNoAnnotations` method persist. And, in [1.9.5](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5/org/mockito/internal/configuration/InjectingAnnotationEngine.java?av=f) version - this method is gone.

I think, that you will get rid of this error by updating versions of frameworks you use.

Comment: Your solution helped me. Updating both powermock and mockito to latest versions, resolved the issue.